# Get most recent file(s) in a directory?

Tags: files-and-directories

`FileNames` retrieves a list of all files in a directory. But is there a way to order these files by their most recent modification time?

Comment: Try this: `SortBy[FileNames["*", {Directory[]}], FileDate]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin that would make a good answer (it works).

Comment: @C.E. Done as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `FileDate`. It returns a `DateObject`, and is therefore directly suitable to be used in `SortBy`. For example:

```
 SortBy[FileNames["*", {Directory[]}], FileDate]
```

`FileDate` takes an optional second argument, which can specify types of changes one is interested in: `"Access"`, `"Change"`, `"Creation"`, and `"Modification"`, with the latter being the default (see [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileDate.html) for more details).